# Set unfocused window to grayscale - WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, grayscale

I've got an colorful application which I want to display in grayscale when it's not focused.

This is what the application looks like when focused:

*-- HA! 10 reputation needed to add pictures.*

---

Anyway, the top bar already changes to gray thanks to [mahapps](http://mahapps.com/) (metro), but the content is still colored when the window is unfocused. Is there a way to put some kind of layer on the content? 
While searching on this topic, I only got flooded by questions on how to convert an image to grayscale.

There are `TabControls`, `Labels`, `Buttons`, `WebBrowsers`, `TextBlocks` and all kind of stuff in my application, and all the content is contained in a `grid`, if that helps.

---

Any thoughts on this are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using PixelShaders to create a WPF Effect. It would be a very long answer to explain it all.

See this link for a full guide on how to create and use a greyscale pixel shader effect:
[Grayscale Effect - A Pixel Shader Effect in WPF](http://bursjootech.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/grayscale-effect-pixel-shader-effect-in.html)

Apply the effect to each Window as and when required.

Comment: That's sweet! I rebuild the project described in the post and it works fine. But it is again only applying on IMAGES! Do you know how I am able to use this Pixel Shader with all my controls, without setting each and every control to this effect?

Comment: Apply the effect to the Window?

Comment: I just tried it. Works for me. Whole window is grayscale.

Comment: Could you please provide the code? Are you using Event Handlers (in the code behind) or EventTrigger (xaml) to apply the effect when unfocused?

Comment: I'm at work and can't access the files I need. Apply the effect on the LostFocus event and remove it on GotFocus.

Comment: That's not the problem, I know how to work with Event Handlers. I just don't know how to apply the effect on the window. I am not in a hurry, I can wait until you have access to those files.

Comment: this.Effect = new GrayscaleEffect()